# How do I override a method in WCF Resfull service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I found a post explain to put

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetDataWithNumber")]
public User GetName(int id)

[OperationContract(Name = "GetDataWithString")]
public User GetName(string email)
```

This wont work if I use Restfull service!

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetDataWithNumber")]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Service/GetName?id={id}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public User GetName(int id)
```

Anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend just using two methods:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "GetDataWithNumber")]
public User GetNameFromId(int id)

[OperationContract(Name = "GetDataWithString")]
public User GetNameFromEmail(string email)
```

This will eliminate the confusion, as well as be more explicit.  As the REST service is going to be translating from a text-based representation, the explicit nature is very useful in terms of maintainability.

Comment: I want to use the same method just because user could send me the id or email.

Comment: @HardCode: Then you'll need to make one method that takes a string, and determine within the method whether it's an ID or an email.  That being said, I think it's better to use two, and make your API explicit - it's more clear for the end user AND for you.